# Print array in node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I  have a website from witch I can send a message to node js server and there the message is saved in a a array. When a new message is sent to the server the old message in the array is overwritten by the new message. The array has to contain new and old messages.
[The output of console after sending message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPkGd.png)

```js
const http = require('http');
const { Socket } = require('socket.io');
const WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var steviloSporocil = 0;
const sporocila=[];

const server = http.createServer();
console.log('Server is on port 3000')
server.listen(3000);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        sporocila[steviloSporocil]=[message.utf8Data];
        steviloSporocil++;
        for (let i = 0; i < steviloSporocil; i++) {
            connection.sendUTF(sporocila[i]);
            console.log('Received Message:', sporocila[i]);
        }

    });

    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log('Client has disconnected.');
    });
});
```

```html
<?php ob_start() ?>
    <?php $titel="Chat"; ?>

    <div class="chat-main" id="text"></div>

    <form name='form' method='post' class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textbox" name="chat" placeholder="Chat">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="gumb" id="gumb" onclick="Poslji()" autocomplete="off">Send</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        <script>
            function Poslji(){
                const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000'); 
                ws.onopen = function() {
                    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
                    ws.send(document.getElementById('textbox').value);
                };
            
                ws.onmessage = function(e) {
                    console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=e.data;
                };   
            }
    </script>
<?php 
    $content=ob_get_clean();
    require "layout.html.php";
?>
```

Comment: Please provide more details around where you stand with the code provided.. does it return any errors? Does it partially work?

Comment: the code displays only the newest message

Comment: I also noticed that in the server console the old and the new messages are displayd but not in the website

Comment: The console in your image shows all the messages in the array as it should. What is the problem? The array *does* contain old and new messages.

Comment: yes but the messages shoud be visible on the website not just in the console

Answer (score 0):

If I understood everything, here how to solve your problem:
you take all previous message at the specified index and add the new one at the end. If you want to add it at the top, then just invert the two lines.

```
sporocila[steviloSporocil] = [
  ...sporocila[steviloSporocil],
  message.utf8Data
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the messages in the array to the client separately using a for-loop and `connection.sendUTF(sporocila[i]);` and then displaying the last message received using `document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=e.data;`.

Are you suprised then that your website only shows the last item in the array?

Why not send the entire array using `JSON.stringify` and then `JSON.parse` on the client?

Comment: Never used JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

Comment: `connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(sporocila));` and then `const arr = JSON.parse(e.data);` in the `onmessage` handler which will give you an array. Best though to read up about those important functions.

Comment: Thanks for help. Now it works how it should